# How to filter a variable by a property included in the variable in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want to write a SPARQL query that would return the first name of a person based on the ranking of the name on Wikidata.

For example, let's say I want the second first name of Mozart (Chrysostom).

This is what I have so far (Mozart Wikidata ID is Q254, first name's property is P735, with P1545 giving the ordinal position of the name):

```
  SELECT DISTINCT ?full_name ?full_nameLabel ?first_nameLabel ?rank 
    WHERE
                      {
                        VALUES ?full_name {wd:Q254} .
                        ?full_name p:P735 [pq:P1545 ?rank] ;
                        p:P735 [ps:P735 ?first_name] ; 
                        FILTER regex(?rank, "2")
                        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
                      }
```

However here the filter only applies to the `rank` variable, and not on the `first_name` variable:

Query result:

[image: Query result]

I think that the problem comes from the fact that the `rank` property is a sub-element of the `first_name` property.  Would you know of a way to filter the `first_name` variable by the `rank` variable?

Comment: you have to get the value from the same blank node representing a statement with the wanted rank: `SELECT DISTINCT ?id ?idLabel ?first_nameLabel 
    WHERE
                      {
                        VALUES ?id {wd:Q254} .
                        ?id p:P735 [pq:P1545 "2" ; ps:P735 ?first_name] ;
                        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
                      }`

Comment: or if you want the rank as well, `SELECT DISTINCT ?id ?idLabel ?first_nameLabel ?rank
    WHERE
                      {
                        VALUES ?id {wd:Q254} .
                        ?id p:P735 [pq:P1545 ?rank ; ps:P735 ?first_name]
                            FILTER(?rank = "2")
                        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
                      }` - no `regex` necessary

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer @UninformedUser, it works! Could you turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?id ?idLabel ?first_nameLabel ?rank
    WHERE {
        VALUES ?id {wd:Q254} .
        ?id p:P735 [
            pq:P1545 ?rank; 
            ps:P735 ?first_name
        ] 
        FILTER(?rank = "2")
        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }           
    }
```